# dequeueReusableCell not dequeuing after 3 cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a uicollectionview inside another uicollectionview. When I scroll through cells horizontally, as you can see, the "top cells" (the ones that contains the other collectionview) are not being dequeued :

[image]

As you can see, "Randonnées" is the same as "Aborigènes".

I've tried prepareForReuse(), quite everywhere I can, but it doesn't seems to work. I know other people encountered a quite similar issue, but none of the relative topics worked for me :/

Here's some of my code :

```
class X3ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

// MARK: Variables
let cellID = "pouet"
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var cell : X3ContentCollectionViewCell?

// MARK: UI
let titleView : UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

 var mainCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    view.collectionViewLayout = layout
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    view.isPagingEnabled = true
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    return view
}()

var menuBar: X3MenuBar?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(delegate.ds.X3data)
}

// MARK: ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    mainCollectionView.dataSource = self
    mainCollectionView.delegate = self
    mainCollectionView.register(X3ContentCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    menuBar = X3MenuBar()
    menuBar?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    menuBar?.rootController = self
    addMenuScrollView()
    addMainView()

}

// MARK: Methods
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return delegate.ds.X3data!.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell = mainCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as? X3ContentCollectionViewCell
    cell?.indexOfContent = indexPath.row
    return cell!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height-25)
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    let itemIndex = Int(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / screenWidth)
    menuBar?.scrollToItemIndex(item: itemIndex)

}

func scrollToItemIndex(item: Int)  {
    mainCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath(row: item, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
delegate.ds.X3index = item
}



//MARK: UI Methods


func addMainView() {
    view.addSubview(mainCollectionView)
    mainCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (menuBar?.view.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true
    mainCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    mainCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    mainCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func addTitleView() {
    view.addSubview(titleView)
    titleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    titleView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    titleView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    titleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: delegate.gfx.X1ViewTitleHeigth!).isActive = true
}

func addMenuScrollView() {
    view.addSubview((menuBar?.view)!)
    menuBar?.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar?.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar?.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    menuBar?.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true

}

deinit {
    delegate.ds.X3data = nil
}

}
```

And the other important part :

```
class X3ContentCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

let cellId = "pouet"
let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
var indexOfContent = 0

 var customCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    let cv  = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.collectionViewLayout = layout

    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    cv.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return cv

}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    customCollectionView.register(X3ContentMenuCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    customCollectionView.dataSource = self
    customCollectionView.delegate = self
    addSubview(customCollectionView)
    customCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    customCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
    customCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    customCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    customCollectionView.reloadData()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ((delegate.ds.X3data?[self.indexOfContent] as! NSDictionary)["images"] as! NSArray).count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
    return CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 170)
    } else if indexPath.item == 3 {
        return CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: 170)
    }else {
        return CGSize(width: frame.size.width/2, height: 120)
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = customCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! X3ContentMenuCellCollectionViewCell
    print((((delegate.ds.X3data?[self.indexOfContent] as! NSDictionary)["images"] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)["image"])
    cell.X3Label.text = "\((((delegate.ds.X3data![self.indexOfContent] as! NSDictionary)["images"] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)["image"]!) \(self.indexOfContent)"
    cell.X3ImageView.image = UIImage(named: (((delegate.ds.X3data?[self.indexOfContent] as! NSDictionary)["images"] as! NSArray)[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)["image"] as! String)
    cell.X3ImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    cell.X3ImageView.clipsToBounds = true

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        cell.X3Label.font = delegate.gfx.font(style: 2)
    } else if indexPath.item == 3 {
        cell.X3Label.font = delegate.gfx.font(style: 2)
    }else {
        cell.X3Label.font = delegate.gfx.font(style: 4)
    }
    return cell
}



deinit {
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mrabins is right. Try this and see if it works. Seems like when indexOfContent is set, your data is ready. So just reload it.

```
var indexOfContent = 0 {
   didSet {
       customCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: great scott ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly. You're failing to call reloadData() when you need to reload the content.

Also, if you're overriding prepareForReuse() why do you have an empty implementation

Comment: Because I tried some things and just let the method over there just in case. Why ? Is it wrong ?
Regarding the reloadData(), where do you think I should put it?

Comment: Well, overriding with an empty method does nothing. If you're testing it at least do something in the declaration. My bad you are calling customCollectionView.reloadData()  That looks like it handles the second collection view. Where's the implementation of the second cell set up? I would call it after setting up the cells UI